# jquery validate, should validate all the fields when pressed on button for required="required"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What i want is when i press submit all the fields should validate.

Well they do validate but i have to use `name=""`. and i dont want to use different names for every field `name=""`
i want only i put required="required", then it just gives error on empty input box.

i tried to forked someones code to show you what i want..

http://jsfiddle.net/vnbzuxsc/3/

Here in demo, when i click i want all the boxes to say feild is required or some error message,

But without using name="" attribute. only using required="required"

Comment: I don't think it is possible because, the validator framework internally uses the name attribute to differentiate the different elements

Comment: @ArunPJohny
So if i have to have too many feilds in my Application, i will have to make a mess of JS.. :(

Comment: @SizzlingCode not really.. see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rw1nh32m/1/

Comment: BTW you don't need to use `required="required"`, you can just use `required` (unless you need your code to conform to XHTML for some reason).